# When SQL Server sorts in tempdb, does it store the whole row or just PK?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are running out of tempdb space when a given query that requires sorting is run. We have a couple of theories about how to solve it but it depends on what SQL Server is storing in tempdb.

Does it store the whole row or does it just store the primary key? Or does it perhaps also store the columns that are required for the sort?

We're using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that simple... sorting what? You mean during an index build or a query?

From this reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/sort-in-tempdb-option-for-indexes

> here must be sufficient free space in tempdb to store the sort runs.
>   These include the data rows of the table. There must be sufficient
>   free space in the destination filegroup to store the final index
>   structure. This includes the data rows of the table and the index
>   B-tree.

So it **can** store the whole data row in scenarios, additionally it may store the BTree of the index, and a sort may require multiple 'runs' so it may actually be more than this.

What are you actually trying to accomplish?  I can't see why this information would dictate what you do to resolve it... If it really will, you can test by creating a table with large columns, forcing the sort, then looking at how much space is used in TempDB to confirm.

Can you not prevent the sort by using correct indexing / rewriting the query?

You may wish to have a read of this article and try the suggestions: https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2010/08/sorting-row-goals-and-the-top-100-problem.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That's the information I was looking for.